# C compiler using variable defined in Fortran module on Cray

Tags: c, fortran, cray

I want to use an integer variable (lets say xyz) defined in a f90 module (abc) in a c program. I have found that with gnu compilers it can be done like this:

```
extern int __abc_MOD_xyz;
```

But I could not find the corresponding syntax for Cray compilers.

**Update**

Following the friendly reminder to read the manual and the other comments, I was able to get it working. Here is the sample FORTRAN module:

```
module test
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
  integer :: ftnint = 100
  BIND(C) :: ftnint
end module test
```

and the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ISO_Fortran_binding.h>
// variable that matches up with the FORTRAN module variable
int ftnint;

int main()
{
  printf(" var2 : %d\n", ftnint );
}
```

Compile with

```
ftn -c test_mod.f90
cc -c test.c
cc test.o test_mod.o
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation of both your C compiler and your Fortran compiler?

Comment: Can you modify your Fortran source? (Such as to change `integer xyz` to `integer, bind(c) :: xyz`.)

Comment: Just to add to @francescalus if you can change the Fortran there is a standard way to do this within the language

Comment: You should write your "Update" as the answer to your question and accept it.